# Onde posso obter uma IDE VB6?

Tags: visual-basic-6, ide

Onde posso encontrar uma IDE VB6? Preciso de uma IDE que eu consiga depurar uma aplicação legada em **VB6**. Não posso migrar para o VB.NET, pois é  uma aplicação que está rodando na empresa.

Comment: O mesmo IDE do VB.NET.